# Is it possible to increase the width of the grid lines on the Kendo UI Scheduler so that it is more obvious which day which in the Timeline View?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I'm using the Kendo UI Scheduler where I added "Slot Templates" to define the color of each slot on the scheduler but I would like to make it more obvious the difference between each day by having a thicker line shown in this picture below. Can someone help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the CSS that I added to my page to make the border of the cells more visible:

```
   <style>
      .k-scheduler-table td{
          border-color:red;
          border-width: 0 0 1px 3px;
       }
   </style>
```

Here is my test dojo - https://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/awAFOfep

Greetings, 
Plamen

Answer (score 0):

Fine-tune this to your needs, but here's a start:

```
#scheduler .k-scheduler-table td:not(:first-child), 
#scheduler .k-scheduler-table th:not(:first-child) {
    border-left-width: 8px; 
}    

.k-event {
    margin-left: 8px; 
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/IhijUNeB)

Comment: Thanks for you help it's much appreciated.....however I only want the "major tick" lines to have thicker lines to show the difference in days not the hours in between, as per the original image.

Comment: What scheduler view are you using?

Comment: I'm using the timeline view.

Comment: I'm using the timeline view (Month)